# Cannot connect to certain website

Tags: linux, browser, connection

I have quite a strange problem. I cannot login to a certain website. I can acces the website, but the website hangs when I try logging in. I tried multiple browsers on my machine. I even have tried logging in from another OS, as I have dual boot, this does not work either. I have tried flushing my DNS-Cache, requesting another IP-Address from my router, nothing works. I can log in from another machine from the same local network, just not from this specific one. I really am confused, as there are no displayed errors to go after.

Edit:
I run Windows and Fedora on both I have installed Wireshark, which probably does not matter. For the browser I tried freshly installed Firefox, Chromium and GNOME Web. I have also tried connecting to another network and connecting through Ethernet. I also tried a connection trough my Phone by tethering. On every other device including the phone the logging works only on this specific machine it does not, which does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Can another device (computer or phone) on the same router get to the website in question?

Comment: Yes this is possible.

Comment: Did you try pinging the website from the working and non-working machine and compare the resolved IP addresses and if both get ping replies? If the site doesn't offer a ping response, use nslookup to resolve address and compare.

Comment: Since your one device with two operating systems fails, also try a different USB wired Ethernet card to see if that works.

Comment: I tried pinging but the website does not allow it.

Comment: resolve the site using nslookup as I mentioned in my comment, then

Comment: On both machines the output is the same, namely the address of my router and the IP of the website.

Comment: I think we need a lot more information in your main post to go further.  What is your alternate OS. Is it a fully clean/stock OS or does it have same software/configuration as main OS, what browser are you using, have you tried alternate browsers on both systems, have you tried incognito mode, disabled all browser plugins, etc...

Comment: I tried to log in from the same machine but using another local network. It worked one time. The second time I tried to log in I got the same behavior as before...